# WARNING: The script pyflakes is installed in '/home/hemanth/.local/bin' which is not on PATH

Tags: git

While installing git graph from https://pypi.org/project/git-graph/ all files were downloaded but at last it showed *WARNING: The script pyflakes is installed in '/home/hemanth/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.* and finally after initialising and  commiting changes into I ran git graph but it showed error as command git graph not found. Also *git-graph --version* command is showing command git-graph not found.

I tried reinstalling after deleting the graphviz and git-graph again and again but it showed the same error. Once it showed all the commits in texts in terminal itself and but it didn't generated a pdf.

Comment: _"but at last it showed some disclaimer like not a PATH"_ aaaand that would be your problem. What that message was telling you is that the directory pip installs scripts to isn't on your PATH. You need to add that directory to your PATH.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe appropriate for https://askubuntu.com

Comment: So add it to your PATH!

Answer (score 1):

Both the error you mentioned, one of command git-graph not found and another of showing texts but not generating pdf of graph has caused because of its installation of the script pyflakes and git-graph in a directory which is not a PATH variable. Since it is installed in the directory */home/hemanth/.local/bin* which is not on PATH, therefore you should add it to PATH.

For adding the directory as PATH variable, have a look at this tutorial
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-add-to-path
and remember you have to add that specific directory in PATH not root as shown as demo in the tutorial. After adding it to the PATH, **restart your computer** and try the `git-graph --version` command and also check `git graph` command in your git directory.